# Ensure GraphQL ID is a Mongo ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo Server to build a graphql based server that interfaces with a MongoDB instance.  I want to make it so that if the client passes a value for a field that has a graphql type of ID, the value must be a valid mongo ObjectId (mongoose has a util to check this I think -- that's not the issue). That is, if the value isn't a valid ObjectId, I would expect to get a validation error at the graphql level (i.e. a 400). I don't want to get a 500 later in my server when I try to use that value as an ObjectId, and I don't want to have to check that the value is a valid ObjectId at multiple places within the server.

Basically I want to implement validation logic at the graphql level for the ID scalar type, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to utilize a [custom scalar](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/scalars/#custom-scalars) instead of `ID` to get the sort of behavior you're looking for. You can write your own or use an [existing one](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars#objectid).

```
import { Kind, GraphQLError, GraphQLScalarType, ValueNode } from 'graphql';

const MONGODB_OBJECTID_REGEX = /*#__PURE__*/ new RegExp(/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{24}$/);

export const GraphQLObjectID = /*#__PURE__*/ new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'ObjectID',

  description:
    'A field whose value conforms with the standard mongodb object ID as described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectId. Example: 5e5677d71bdc2ae76344968c',

  serialize(value: string) {
    if (!MONGODB_OBJECTID_REGEX.test(value)) {
      throw new TypeError(
        `Value is not a valid mongodb object id of form: ${value}`,
      );
    }

    return value;
  },

  parseValue(value: string) {
    if (!MONGODB_OBJECTID_REGEX.test(value)) {
      throw new TypeError(
        `Value is not a valid mongodb object id of form: ${value}`,
      );
    }

    return value;
  },

  parseLiteral(ast: ValueNode) {
    if (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING) {
      throw new GraphQLError(
        `Can only validate strings as mongodb object id but got a: ${ast.kind}`,
      );
    }

    if (!MONGODB_OBJECTID_REGEX.test(ast.value)) {
      throw new TypeError(
        `Value is not a valid mongodb object id of form: ${ast.value}`,
      );
    }

    return ast.value;
  },
});
```